# Template error in Angular

Tags: typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angular5, angularfire2

I'm trying to create a list of elements. Here's my html template:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items | async">
  <item-detail [item]='item'></item-detail>
</div>
<button (click)='deleteItems()'>Delete Entire List</button>
```

So, I'm just trying to iterate through the list. Unfortunately I'm getting this:

```
Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'item' since it isn't a known property of 'item-detail'.
```

Here's my `item-list.component.ts`.

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {FirebaseListObservable, FirebaseObjectObservable, AngularFireDatabase} from 'angularfire2/database-deprecated';
import {Item} from '../shared/item';
import {ItemService} from '../shared/item.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-items-list',
  templateUrl: './items-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./items-list.component.scss']
})

export class ItemsListComponent implements OnInit {
  public items: FirebaseListObservable<Item[]>;
  constructor(private itemSvc: ItemService) {
  }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.items = this.itemSvc.getItemsList({limitToLast: 5});
  }
}
```

I'm following this tutorial: https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/reactive-crud-app-with-angular-and-firebase-tutorial/

`item-details.component.ts` file

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {Input} from '@angular/core';
import {Item} from '../shared/item';
import {ItemService} from '../shared/item.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-item-detail',
  templateUrl: './item-detail.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./item-detail.component.scss']
})
export class ItemDetailComponent {
  @Input() item: Item;

  constructor(private itemSvc: ItemService) {
  }

  updateTimeStamp() {
    this.itemSvc.updateItem(this.item.firebaseKey, {});
  }

  updateActive(value: boolean) {
    this.itemSvc.updateItem(this.item.firebaseKey, {});
  }
}
```

Follow up error:

```
Can't bind to 'item' since it isn't a known property of 'app-items-list'.
```

New code:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items | async">
  <app-items-list [item]='item'></app-items-list>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you post the TS file of your `item-detail` component? Most likely you haven't defined the input property correctly

Comment: Sorry, I didn't even know they're correlated.

Comment: item detail selector should be ```selector: 'item-detail'```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the selector of your `item-detail` component is defined as `'app-item-detail'`, which means that Angular is looking for `<app-item-detail>` tags in your HTML.

However, you have used `<item-detail [item]='item'></item-detail>` and angular doesn't know what `item-detail` is. Change it to `<app-item-detail [item]='item'></app-item-detail>` and all will be fine.

---

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items | async">
  <app-item-detail [item]='item'></app-item-detail>
</div>
```

Comment: Oooooh ok. So I can either change it in the component, or in the template?

Comment: Yes, you can do both. However, the convention is to prefix component selectors  with the app's name (which usually defaults to `app`), so I would keep `app-item-detail`

Comment: Make sure of the following: 1) `ItemDetailComponent` is correctly imported in your `app.module` 2) the selector of `ItemDetailComponent` is `'app-item-detail'`

Comment: I have two files. `item-details.component.ts` and `item-list.component.ts`. Now, both of them are using `<app-item-detail [item]='item'></app-item-detail>`. Is this correct? If I set the template to `<app-items-list [item]='item'></app-items-list>` it narrows the error to: `Can't bind to 'item' since it's not a known property of 'app-items-list'`